# Changing IRepository to support IQueryable (LINQtoSQL queries)

Tags: linq-to-sql, dependency-injection, castle-windsor, iqueryable

I've inherited a system that uses the Castle Windsor IRepository pattern to abstract away from the DAL which is LinqToSQL.

The main problem that I can see, is that IRepository only implements IEnumerable. So even the simplest of queries have to load ALL the data from the datatable, to return a single object.

Current usage is as follows

```
using (IUnitOfWork context2 = IocServiceFactory.Resolve<IUnitOfWork>())
       {
           KpiFormDocumentEntry entry = context2.GetRepository<KpiFormDocumentEntry>().FindById(id, KpiFormDocumentEntry.LoadOptions.FormItem);
```

And this uses lambda to filter, like so

```
public static KpiFormDocumentEntry FindById(this IRepository<KpiFormDocumentEntry> source, int id, KpiFormDocumentEntry.LoadOptions loadOptions)
    {
        return source.Where( qi => qi.Id == id ).LoadWith( loadOptions ).FirstOrDefault();
    }
```

So it becomes a nice extension method.

**My Question is**, how can I use this same Interface/pattern etc. but also implement IQueryable to properly support LinqToSQL and get some serious performance improvements?

The current implementation/Interfaces for IRepository are as follows

```
public interface IRepository<T> : IEnumerable<T> where T : class
{

    void Add(T entity);

    void AddMany(IEnumerable<T> entities);

    void Delete(T entity);


    void DeleteMany(IEnumerable<T> entities);

    IEnumerable<T> All();

    IEnumerable<T> Find(Func<T, bool> predicate);

    T FindFirst(Func<T, bool> predicate);
}
```

and then this is implemented by an SqlClientRepository like so

```
public sealed class SqlClientRepository<T> : IRepository<T> where T : class
{
    private readonly Table<T> _source;

    internal SqlClientRepository(Table<T> source)
    {
        if( source == null ) throw new ArgumentNullException( "source", Gratte.Aurora.SHlib.labelText("All_TableIsNull",1) );
        _source = source;
    }

    //removed add delete etc 

    public IEnumerable<T> All()
    {
        return _source;
    }

    public IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator()
    {
        return _source.GetEnumerator();
    }

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return GetEnumerator();
    }
}
```

**The problem at the moment** is, in our example above, the .Where is calling 'GetEnumerator', which then loads all rows into memory, and then looks for the one we need.

If I change IRepository to implement IQueryable, I can't implement the three methods needed, as these are not public in the Table class.

I think I should change the SQLClientRepository to be defined like so

```
public sealed class SqlClientRepository<T> : IQueryable<T>, IRepository<T> where T : class
```

And then implement the necessary methods, but I can't figure out how to pass the expressions around etc. as they are private members of the Table class, like so

```
public override Type ElementType
    {
        get { return _source.ElementType; } //Won't work as ElementType is private
    }

    public override Expression Expression
    {
        get { return _source.Expression; } //Won't work as Expression is private
    }

    public override IQueryProvider Provider
    {
        get { return _source.Provider; } //Won't work as Provider is private
    }
```

Any help really appreciated to move this from 'iterate through every row in the database after loading it' to 'select x where id=1'!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, while it may not be a true abstraction any longer, the main point was to get the benefit of linq to sql without updating all the queries already written.

so, I made the IRepository implement IQueryable instead of IEnumerable.

then in the SqlClientRepository implementation, I can call AsQueryable() to cast the Table to IQueryable, and then all is good, like so.

Now everywhere somebody has written IRepository().Where(qi => qi.id = id) or similar, it actually passes the ID to sql server and only pulls back one record, instead of all of them, and loops through looking for the correct one.

```
/// <summary>Provides the ability to query and access entities within a SQL Server data store.</summary>
/// <typeparam name="T">The type of entity in the repository.</typeparam>
public sealed class SqlClientRepository<T> : IRepository<T> where T : class
{
    private readonly Table<T> _source;
    private readonly IQueryable<T> _sourceQuery;

    IQueryable<T> Query()
    {
        return (IQueryable<T>)_source;
    }

    public Type ElementType
    {
        get { return _sourceQuery.GetType(); }
    }

    public Expression Expression
    {
        get { return _sourceQuery.Expression; }
    }

    public IQueryProvider Provider
    {
        get { return _sourceQuery.Provider; }
    }



    /// <summary>Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="SqlClientRepository{T}"/> class.</summary>
    /// <param name="source">A <see cref="Table{T}"/> to a collection representing the entities from a SQL Server data store.</param>
    /// <exception cref="ArgumentNullException"><paramref name="source"/> is a <c>null</c> reference (<c>Nothing</c> in Visual Basic).</exception>
    internal SqlClientRepository(Table<T> source)
    {
        if( source == null ) throw new ArgumentNullException( "source", "All_TableIsNull" ) );
        _source = source;
        _sourceQuery = _source.AsQueryable();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to expose linq you can stop using the repository pattern and use Linq2Sql directly. The reason to this is that every Linq To Sql provider has it's own custom solutions. So if you expose LINQ you get a leaky abstraction. There is no point in using an abstraction layer then.

Instead of exposing LINQ you got two options:

1. Implement the specification pattern
2. Use the repository pattern as I describe here: http://blog.gauffin.org/2013/01/repository-pattern-done-right/

Comment: Thanks for that. Yes actually that's exactly what I was doing in some places, but in this respect I wanted the benefit without rewriting everything we'd already done. I'll take a look at your article. Thanks.